# I am using pawlox/video-thumbnail to generate thumbnail but the thumbnail fails to save in my drive

Tags: php, laravel, api, file-io, video-thumbnails

When I run this code I get success as output, but there is no image saved in "D:/thumbs" which is the destination file name. Please help me.

```
if(VideoThumbnail::createThumbnail(storage_path('D:/a.mp4'), storage_path('D:/thumbs'), 'thumb.jpg', 2, 1920, 1080)){
  $response = json_encode(array("response_code"=>200, "response_message"=>"Success"));
  return $response;
} else {
  $response = json_encode(array("response_code"=>250, "response_message"=>"Failed"));
  return $response;
}
```

Comment: There are a `storage` folder on your app root. Check there

Comment: I am using Windows 10 OS